# Drawing flot chart in timeseries between 0 and 24 hours

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

Now I'm using **flot** library.

I have a function that draws data, data object looks like:

```
{ "data" : [[temperature1, temp2, temp3,..]] }
```

And i want just to place this array between **0hour** and **24hour**, but my code doesn't work, and it just freezes my page after calling this `func` (Maybe it's to complicated to client to draw about 8000 points)

Format should be timeformat: `"%h:%m"`

```
function plotdata(data) {
var d1 = [];
var increment = 3600/data['data'][0].length;
for (var i = -2211663600; i < data['data'][0].length; i-=increment)  {
  d1.push([i, data['data'][0][i]]);
}

var options = {
    xaxes: [{
      mode: "time",
      timeformat: "%h:%m",
      axisLabel: 'time',
      min: (new Date(0, 0, 0, 00, 00, 00, 00)).getTime(),
      max: (new Date(0, 0, 0, 24, 00, 00, 00)).getTime(),

    }],
    yaxes: [{
        axisLabel: 'y-axis',
    }]
};

$.plot("#plot1d", [ d1 ], options);
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Drawing 8000 points takes a while ... maybe only show every fifth or tenth points depending on the size of the display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop starts at a negative number, decrements, and only ends when it exceeds the length of an array, which is non-negative.  In other words, the loop will never end; it is not even reaching the plot call.

For example, if you had 100 temperatures in the array, the loop would effectively be:

```
for (var i = -2211663600; i < 100; i-=36)  {
```

Once you fix this, plotting 8000 points, as Raidri pointed out, will still be relatively slow; anywhere from a few hundred milliseconds to a few seconds depending on the machine.  You should down-sample in advance if you plan to do any kind of real-time interaction (panning, zooming, etc.) on the plot.